# Daily summary of systemd logs - linux

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, stack-trace

I am looking for any direct way to get the daily summary on systemd logs (probably through mail). Is there any functionality available in linux to get the dailysummary of systemd logs automatically through email. 
Whether we have to write some script to run `journalctl -u <service name>` and transfer the output into some file and then send-out mail using some module ( like `node-mailer` as my service is based on `node.js`)

Answer (score 1):

You should make script for that once and then you can setup cronjob for that.